# The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I am rececing the following error:

```
The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}
```

for the following line:
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

Below is the entire activity code:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String[] mOptionMenu;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private RelativeLayout mDrawerRelativeLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mTitleSection;
    private CharSequence mTitleApp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        mOptionMenu = new String[] { "Opción 1", "Opción 2", "Opción 3" };
         mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
         mDrawerRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)
         findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
         mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_drawer);
         mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar()
         .getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
         mOptionMenu));

         mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
         int position, long id) {

         Fragment fragment = null;

         switch (position) {
         case 0:
         fragment = new FirstFragment();
         break;
         case 1:
         fragment = new SecondFragment();
         break;
         case 2:
         fragment = new ThirdFragment();
         break;
         }

         FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

         fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
         .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

         mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);

         mTitleSection = mOptionMenu[position];
         getActionBar().setTitle(mTitleSection);

         mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerRelativeLayout);
         }
         });
         mDrawerList.setItemChecked(0, true);
         mTitleSection = getTitle();
         mTitleApp = getTitle();

         mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
         R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
         R.string.drawer_close) {

         public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
         getActionBar().setTitle(mTitleSection);
         ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.this);
         }

         public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
         getActionBar().setTitle(mTitleSection);
         ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.this);
         }
         };

         mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

         getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
         getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ;
            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

At first the class was extending ActionBarActivity but I am running on android 4.42 and preferred using activity.

If anyone can assist me, that would be helpful.

If you need any clarification, let me know.

**Update:**

```
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dooba.beta/com.dooba.beta.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #110: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #110: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at com.dooba.beta.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    ... 11 more
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    ... 27 more
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:326)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:499)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    ... 30 more
11-04 06:18:15.093: D/dalvikvm(18955): GC_CONCURRENT freed 161K, 3% free 8309K/8519K, paused 16ms+2ms, total 43ms
```

**Update 2:**

```
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dooba.beta/com.dooba.beta.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #110: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #110: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at com.dooba.beta.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    ... 11 more
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    ... 27 more
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:326)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:499)
11-04 06:16:38.879: E/AndroidRuntime(18850):    ... 30 more
11-04 06:18:15.093: D/dalvikvm(18955): GC_CONCURRENT freed 161K, 3% free 8309K/8519K, paused 16ms+2ms, total 43ms
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dooba.beta/com.dooba.beta.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at com.dooba.beta.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    ... 11 more
```

I believe the error occurs within these lines:

```
 mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar()
         .getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
         mOptionMenu));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Activity` class does not have a `getSupportFragmentManager()` method. Instead make your activity extend `FragmentActivity` which does have.

Comment: thank you for your response. it has indeed cleared the problem, but unforutnatetly while running the application I recieved an error shown in the update section of my inital post

Comment: In one of your XML's, you set an invalid color on one of your TextView's.

Comment: thank you for your prompt response. Its a step forward, but It think changing it to fragmentactivity triggered another error. I have included it under the update 2 section of my initial post.

Comment: There is a NullPointerException at line 51 of your MainActivity. Make sure all views exist in the XML of the Activity, so findViewById(...) does not return a null.

Comment: I see where the problem is. android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 was added in API level 21, I am targetting API 19 so that it could run on my previous devices. Any other list I could use that would satisfy api 19 or below?

Comment: That's not correct, it was added in API level 1. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html#simple_list_item_1

Comment: Instead of getActionBar().getThemedContext(), just use MainActivity.this.

Comment: Thank you. I have recieved another null exception error at the following line:          getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 would I replace every instance of getActionBar() with MainActivity.this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64258/discussion-between-daniel-zolnai-and-user3907211).